# Excel trick, I could not find it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a report and sum several items value:
column a = items have dollar value associated in column b

```
Column A          Column B
bank fee          $20
designer          $1000
developer         $500
bank fee          $30
bank fee          $10
designer          $300
Developer         $230
```

I have over 1000 items in column A and I would like to sum up column B according to items in column A.

What formula can give me:

```
Bank fee = $50
Designer = $1300
...
```

Comment: look up the formula SUMIFS

Comment: [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Comment: Why would Bank fee = $50?

Comment: @Jeeped Think he meant $60

Comment: @freginold - Yeah, he/she put as much effort into writing the question as he/she did researching a basic conditional sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup your spreadsheet like this:

[image]

The formula in `cell E2` is:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,D2,$B$2:$B$8)
```

Just throw out a bonus in case you want to retrieve unique item from `column A` in `column D`.  You can enter an array formula (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together) from `cell D2`.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$8),0)),"")}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [@KresimirL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46570122/5463636), you could do something like this:

```
Column C     Column D
Bank Fee     =SUMIF(A2:A8000,"bank fee",B2:B8000)
Designer     =SUMIF(A2:A8000,"designer",B2:B8000)
Developer    =SUMIF(A2:A8000,"developer",B2:B8000)
```

Each `SUMIF` formula will tally up the totals of any cells in `Column B` for which the value of the corresponding cell in `Column A` matches the specified string. (`Column C` and `Column D` are just placeholders; you can put these formulas wherever you want.)

The search string is not case-sensitive, so "developer" would return both the $500 and $230 results in your example.